# Split single string with many patterns at a time

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a phone/fax number, and i want to split it based on `-` and `()` characters at a single time.

```
String number= "(1234) 567-8910";
```

Comment: I want world peace. Don't expect us to do your homework. Show us your attempts and tell us why they failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tokenizer for splitting with multiple delimiters. Please refer to below code.

```
String number= "(1234) 567-8910";

         StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(number, "()- ");
         String part1 = tokens.nextToken();
         String part2 = tokens.nextToken();
         String part3 = tokens.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with regex `\s*[()-]\s*`. Here `\s*` will omit the all spaces between number.

```
 String[] num=number.split("\\s*[()-]\\s*");
 for (String n : num) {
        System.out.print(" "+n);
 }
```

**Output:** 1234  567 8910

Comment: does this solution takes care of spaces between "(1234) 5"?

Comment: @user2875395, I have edited my regex to take care spaces between. You need \\s* for that.